# Co-Ordinate geometry and trigonometry mixed Question

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

There are three concurrent lines who line equations are :

$$ \big( \cos^2 \mathrm A \big )x + \big (\cos \mathrm A \big )y+1 = 0$$

$$ \big( \cos^2 \mathrm B \big ) x+ \big ( \cos \mathrm B \big )y+1 = 0$$

$$ \big (\cos^2 \mathrm C \big ) x+ \big ( \cos \mathrm C\big )y +1= 0$$

It is also given that A,B,C are angles of a triangle. We should prove that the triangle is isosceles.

---

I understood that by saying that these three are concurrent , all three equations have a common solution. But my problem is , i am not able to find that common solution. Please tell me some idea for finding it and also tell me whether it is required to solve this question.

Comment: Solve the first two equations for $x$ and $y$, then substitute those values into the third equation. This gives you a condition on $A$, $B$, $C$ for the lines to be concurrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compatibility condition for this system is $$\begin{vmatrix}\cos^2A&\cos A&1\\\cos^2B&\cos B&1\\\cos^2C&\cos C&1\\\end{vmatrix}=0.$$

We recognize a $3\times3$ Vandermonde determinant, which equals
$$(\cos A-\cos B)(\cos A-\cos C)(\cos B-\cos C).$$

Hence the cosines of at least two angles are equal.